# Stop a thread with only one operation

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that runs a Runnable and looks like:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        functionCall();
    }

};
Thread thread = new Thread(run);
thread.start();

void functionCall() {
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) System.out.println(i);
}
```

And I would like to stop it no matter what. I've tried with `thread.interrupt()` but I haven't been able to make it work because the `functionCall()` method doesn't really depends on me (I have no idea what's inside that function, this is only an example).

As far as I have seen, everyone uses a volatile boolean variable to check it but this thread is only executed ONCE so it's not really what I need.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how threads work in Java. If the code does not react to the interrupt, there is not much you can do.

Comment: @Thilo _"there is not much you can do"_? So what's the bit he can do?

Comment: Make sure you are interrupting the right thread - it is easy to accidentally interrupt your own thread without noticing your mistake.

Comment: @user714965: "Not much" is just me being polite. Read it as "Nothing really".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.interrupt()` requires the thread being called on to yield control to the OS (for IO access, sleep etc.). So in order to use this you need to ensure that your thread does this (i.e. isn't solely computationally). See [this JavaSpecialists](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) entry for more information.

Comment: To rephrase this:  If the code does not react to the interrupt, there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: Thank you both, actually I didn't understand it on the first hand